# mysql query for getting rows after last specific mark on the list

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem to fiqure out the way to grap rows after last marked value from a table.

```
id  | f_id    | pi         | typeId
 1  |   1     | 10         | 1
 2  |   2     | 24         | 2
 3  |   1     | 34         | 3
 4  |   1     | 56         | 2
 5  |   1     | 12         | 1
 6  |   2     | 34         | 1
 7  |   1     | 65         | 1
 8  |   1     | 19         | 2
 9  |   1     | 38         | 1
 10 |   2     | 27         | 3
 11 |   1     | 21         | 3
```

i need a mysql query for f_id=1 and rows after last typeId=2 (including typeId=2 row) like below:

```
  id  | f_id    | pi         | typeId
   1  |  1      | 19         | 2
   2  |  1      | 38         | 1
   3  |  1      | 21         | 3
```

Comment: How do you know the last entry is there any primary key or timestamp ?

Comment: There is timestamp, i didnt put it to make messy/confusing table. Assume that the list is according to entry time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following

```
mysql> create table test (f_id int, pi int, typeid int,timestamp datetime);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.13 sec)

mysql> insert into test values 
    -> (1,10,1, date_add(now(),interval 1 minute)),
    -> (2,24,2, date_add(now(),interval 2 minute)),
    -> (1,34,3,date_add(now(),interval 3 minute)),
    -> (1,56,2,date_add(now(),interval 4 minute)),
    -> (1,12,1,date_add(now(),interval 5 minute)),
    -> (2,34,1,date_add(now(),interval 6 minute)),
    -> (1,65,1,date_add(now(),interval 7 minute)),
    -> (1,19,2,date_add(now(),interval 8 minute)),
    -> (1,38,1,date_add(now(),interval 9 minute)),
    -> (2,27,3,date_add(now(),interval 10 minute)),
    -> (1,21,3,date_add(now(),interval 11 minute));
Query OK, 11 rows affected (0.08 sec)
Records: 11  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from test ;
+------+------+--------+---------------------+
| f_id | pi   | typeid | timestamp           |
+------+------+--------+---------------------+
|    1 |   10 |      1 | 2015-04-01 16:53:01 |
|    2 |   24 |      2 | 2015-04-01 16:54:01 |
|    1 |   34 |      3 | 2015-04-01 16:55:01 |
|    1 |   56 |      2 | 2015-04-01 16:56:01 |
|    1 |   12 |      1 | 2015-04-01 16:57:01 |
|    2 |   34 |      1 | 2015-04-01 16:58:01 |
|    1 |   65 |      1 | 2015-04-01 16:59:01 |
|    1 |   19 |      2 | 2015-04-01 17:00:01 |
|    1 |   38 |      1 | 2015-04-01 17:01:01 |
|    2 |   27 |      3 | 2015-04-01 17:02:01 |
|    1 |   21 |      3 | 2015-04-01 17:03:01 |
+------+------+--------+---------------------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The query will first get the result with first condition ordering by timestamp column and the union all to get the rest after the first record

```
(  
  select * from test where f_id = 1 and typeid = 2 order by timestamp desc limit 1
)
union all
(
  select * from test t1 where t1.f_id = 1 and t1.timestamp > ( select max(timestamp) from test t2 where t2.f_id = 1 and t2.typeid = 2 )
) ;
```

The result will be

```
+------+------+--------+---------------------+
| f_id | pi   | typeid | timestamp           |
+------+------+--------+---------------------+
|    1 |   19 |      2 | 2015-04-01 17:00:01 |
|    1 |   38 |      1 | 2015-04-01 17:01:01 |
|    1 |   21 |      3 | 2015-04-01 17:03:01 |
+------+------+--------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Myabe help you:

```
select id, max(f_id), max(pi), max(typeId)
    from TABLE
    where f_id=1 and typeID=1
    group by id
    order by max(f_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can express this as a `join` by getting the maximum `id` from the table for

```
select t.*
from table t cross join
     (select max(id) as maxid
      from table
      where typeId = 2
     ) t2
where t.id = t2.id or
      (t.id > t2.id and t.f_id = 1)
```

This answers the question as I understand it -- where the "2" value can be on any row and you want that row returned even if its `f_id <> 1`.  It is ambiguous about whether the "2" value should be on a row where `f_id = 1`.  If so, the logic would be slightly different.